# Xvfb appears like already running, but no lock found

Tags: linux, xvfb

I'm trying to launch Xvfb on a specific display, but I get this error message:

```
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 42
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X42-lock
    and start again.
(EE)
```

But when I look for `/tmp/.X42-lock`, it doesn't exist. How can I do to make the display 42 available again?
(I've tried with other displays, I works the first time, but then the display is not available anymore, which seems logic).

I've found a workaround but I think it's not very clean:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'Xvfb' | awk '{print $2}')
// or...
killall Xvfb
```

I would like to know if there's a cleaner way to stop Xvfb processes.

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has a list of other SE sites that you can look through to find one appropriate for your question (e.g. [unix.se]).

Comment: Xvfb is often used for functional testing in CI systems, I disagree with the closing vote.

Comment: Thank you @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ. I'm actually using Xvfb for my CI process in Jenkins (automated tests with Protractor).